# Where is the correct place to call session_start()?

Tags: php, authentication

There seem to be two principle ways of setting out a login system with PHP from the code I have studied as a beginner. I would like to know which is the "better" way to do it.

The first way calls `session_start()` in the header of every page, regardless of whether the user is logged in or not. The login script when called adds variables via `$_SESSION`. If the variables match the Users table then the user is logged in and gains access to the login area.

The second way first calls `session_start()` in the login script, and then in every further page within the user area.

- Given that `session_start()` needs to be called to create or resume sessions, is best practice simply to put it in the header and forget about it?

OR

- Should `session_start()` be called for the first time in the login script?

What are the implications of this decision?

Comment: Option 1 is your best bet.

Comment: It should be called as soon as possible, ideally in some form of “bootstrap” or set-up script for your application. You don’t want to be hunting down bugs because you have `session_start()` in some pages and not others.

Comment: @MartinBean It seemed counterintuitive to me to start sessions for users who will not login so for whom it doesn't have any purpose; but I take it this is inconsequential. Thank you.

Comment: and be sure you call it before any output is/can be sent to the browser. As it leads to a Headers-Already-Sent error

Comment: you need session information to find out if a user is logged in.
apart from that: you can store more than just login information. fi.opened menu items, etc

Comment: @HenryPopiolek Sessions can be used for things other than user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

> The first way calls session_start() in the header of every page, regardless of whether the user is logged in or not.

This is ideally the best option for a number of reasons.

Maybe additional functionality can be added for security (or other reasons) from the very start. For example, maybe you could have some blocked IP addresses which you do not want to access your website, or you could use the session for gaining statistics.

So maybe you want to see where a person was redirected from to get to a certain page, even when they are not logged in.

Overall it helps to develop easier session management for security reasons and develop statistic functions.